# Maven build throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testing, jacoco

SOLVED: My class resource was named TestCounter... maven was trying to test it. Renamed it to CounterSwitch and build was successful.

I'm very new to maven, please bear with me... I have some tests that run great in eclipse, but fail during a maven build.

The tests are in: `src/test/java/main/*.java`

The tests use test-only classes in: `src/test/java/**/*.java`

The tests also require access to resources located in: `src/test/resources/packages/etc...`

Within my resources are `.java` source files that I am *not* compiling, but am using for `JaCoCo` analysis tests. I'm loading these resources using relative pathed File objects since resource loader insists on using absolute pathing and causes my tests to fail.

Common sense says that the relative pathing changes post-build and that's why maven's throwing `NoClassDefFoundError`, but it's also throwing the exception when it encounters one of the `.java` files... it may be trying to compile it or it may just be a coincidence.

However, the solution may be more convenient as it is *not* necessary for me to run these tests during the maven lifecycle, they're functional tests that are used more for the results they produce and less for their assertions but I have no idea how to blacklist them.

I have two questions: how do I segregate those files from my maven build that are undesirable, and how do I include those files into my maven build that are?

I'd appreciate any help I can get... here's a relevant representation of my pom.xml (plugins make it quite lengthy) for reference, it's almost a default configuration as I have no idea where to begin with it:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.genericpackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>genericartifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>genericartifact</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Stack Trace:

```
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mockprocesses/itclient-counter/bin/main/TestCounter (wrong name: main/TestCounter)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.loadClass(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:98)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.locateTestClasses(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:78)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:174)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:83)
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: What is Maven actually giving you for the error? The error you are seeing is probably during test execution as part of the Test lifecycle step, not during build. Where are your source files located for the "main" portion of your project?

Comment: Use maven to compile, not Eclipse.

Comment: @RyanJ [Here's the stack trace](http://pastebin.com/6yDRjfj5) as testing begins (and fails to even execute.) My tests are affixed with UnitTest.java, maven doesn't even try to run them.

Source files are in src/main/java/main.

The project was testing and building fine before I added my resources, so I must be missing some critical configuration. In fact, the project *builds* fine now, it just fails to execute any tests.

Comment: As @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen has suggested, you should use Maven to compile and run through all necessary steps. Your issue seems to be that it thinks "main" is a package name, not a folder name (that "bin" is your classpath root, not "bin/main", hence the "wrong name" error you can see at the end). Maven handling it should fix it for you. `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mockprocesses/itclient-counter/bin/main/TestCounter (wrong name: main/TestCounter)`

Comment: @RyanJ I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by maven handling it. Maven actually builds the project "successfully" because it's skipping over the test phase entirely. I know it's crap having to use external source files as resources (for JaCoCo report testing) but there must be a solution. I've tried adding exclude tags to my pom for everything under src/test/resources but it's still throwing the same exception:

[Full maven build output](http://pastebin.com/amvsscsc)

Comment: @RyanJ Fixed it, the problem was obvious... the class/java files were named TestCounter... surefire was trying to test them. Renamed them to CounterSwitch and the build went off without a hitch.

Comment: Ahh. Good to hear, I've been burned by that before too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it, the problem was obvious... the class/java files were named TestCounter... surefire was trying to test them. Renamed them to CounterSwitch and the build went off without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, fixed it including the file as part of `maven-surefire-plugin` configuration, as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
          <include>src/main/java/mockprocesses/itclient-counter/bin/main/TestCounter.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```